# HTML Code completion inside PHP Tags in WebStorm IDE

Tags: php, html, autocomplete, webstorm

I'm running WebStorm 7.0.3.

I have PHP files that contain HTML tags. As it currently stands, WebStorm either auto-completes PHP tags OR HTML tags. Is it possible to have it auto-complete both in a php file that contains html tags?

I would like to be able to the following for instance:
**PHP completion**
When I type "in_arr" and hit TAB, it should suggest or complete "`in_array()`" as a PHP function.

**HTML Completion**
When I type "div" and hit tab, it should complete with "`<div></div>`" as an HTML tag.

I want this to happen in the same PHP file.

Is this possible? If so, how do I set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As it currently stands, WebStorm either auto-completes PHP tags OR HTML tags

Hmm... are you sure that you are using WebStorm? It doesn't provide ANY support for PHP, so no completion for PHP is available (it's treated as a plain text). Please try PHPStorm - it does correctly recognize PHP/HTML in .php files and treat them accordingly

Comment: Yes. The "About WebStorm" menu item shows a splash screen that says "WebStorm 7" by JetBrains. I haven't tried PHPStorm. I'll look at it.

Comment: While the WebStorm version I was using did have PHP completion, PHPStorm does what I wanted out of the box. Thanks for the referral.